# Module Not Found Error: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

Whenever I run `main.py` in the terminal, I get the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

However it runs fine in PyCharm.

Project Structure:

```
-project
  -resources
  -src
    -package1
      -script1.py
      -script2.py
    -package2
      -script3.py
    -main.py
```

This is what I run in the terminal:

```
project$ python src/main.py
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.package1 import script1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I have already tried adding absolute path of folder/package 'src' to sys.path

```
main.py
```

```py
from src.package1 import script1
from src.package1 import script2
from src.package2 import script3

if name=="__main__":
  ...
  ...
```

```
sys.path

current sys.path is ['/home/xyz/Projects/project/src', '/home/xyz/Apps/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python37.zip', '/home/xyz/Apps/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.7', '/home/xyz/Apps/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/xyz/Apps/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 'src/main.py']
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Since you supply a file, `src/main.py`, its containing folder is going to be the search root. You could import the modules without specifying the `src.` part.

Comment: You meant "suppy a file" by specifying in sys.path ?

Comment: @Wave: I wanted to point out that the first bullet point applies, as a file (to run) is provided in the command line. As I do not know PyCharm, unfortunately I can not tell how it runs the code, but it may be possible to have a look at how it starts the application. IDE-s usually provide a panel/dialog where additional parameters can be added and sometimes they show the final command line there. Or it might be visible when the application actually starts, and if everything else fails, you can check `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` and `environ` for clues. Perhaps it simply sets `PYTHONPATH` at the end.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to run it with `project$ python -m src.main`

Source: https://qavalidation.com/2021/03/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-src.html/

Answer (score 6):

You can add a path to python runtime using sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('src/package1')
import script1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are chances you encountered such error because you're following the guidelines that told you to put your code in `src/` folder AND you are using PyCharm IDE. It was my case, at least.

My configuration was all good (I'm using `pyproject.toml`), except for one thing... In PyCharm, when importing an internal module I would get something like

```py
from src.my_package.utils.log import log_d
```

The `src` part was the source of the problem, but without it PyCharm wouldn't know how to find the modules.

In PyCharm Preferences
I went to the menu `Project: <my_project>`/`Project Structure`.
Right-click on the `src/` folder you see in the right panel, choose it as `Sources`.

Rename all your internal references without the `src.`part

```py
from my_package.utils.log import log_d
```

Test, rebuild, it should be OK now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was interfering with *src* folder from another project, set in environnent variables.

Comment: Could you explain it more so other might have clue to solve it?

Comment: python was trying to lookup for src folder in another project, that was set among the environment variables