# Python calling modules difference between command line and spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm just starting out adding python to my repertoire, very much learning still.

When I call a .py module from spyder, spyder automatically knows to go to where I'm working on my C drive and imports and runs no problem.

But when I call from command line, exactly the same thing I was doing in spyder, I get an error saying it can't find the module. Why is that and why are the two different?

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>python import script1b
    python: can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Edit 1: I also tried the following

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
    Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    >>> import script1b.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script1b'
```

Edit:
I read the post @nanna feel answers my question. I am an engineer learning coding not a software developer. I can follow follow the other post, install the file etc for command prompt to use, I have done something similar before with other people's code using pip install for tools from Gitlab. I am actually trying to learn more about how modules work so I can start to build them myself. I am referencing the textbook O'Reilly 'learning python' by Mark Lutz. The post referenced seems to be different to what the textbook is telling me I can do through command prompt for windows. Its page 68 import and reload basics for anyone who might happen to have it.

I created a text file containing my python code, named it a .py and was able to open and execute in spyder. Was just wondering what the difference was between Sypder, seems much more involved using command prompt. However my textbook tells me I should be able to run the same text file from command prompt, much more easily that is outlined in the post.

```
%python
>>> import script1
```

is actually what it tells me I can use in command prompt, in an interactive session, this is directly copied from the book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module Not Found Error: No module named 'src'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078689/module-not-found-error-no-module-named-src)

Comment: Hey I read the related post and I'm still not sure. I wanted to know why it is possible to run the text file straight from spyder, but not for command prompt.

Comment: You could run 'import script1' in an interactive session if one of the locations python searches points to the script.  If not you have to include the path to it.  I'm not familiar with spyder, but I'm guessing it does some kind of magic for knowing where to look for the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have python running in the command line to be able to do imports.  First, just type `python` and press enter, and then try the import once python is running.  The following is from a mac terminal, but might help you get the idea:

```
Nannas-computer:somefolder someuser$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec  3 2019, 07:02:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import script1b
```

And just to clarify; `import` is for importing modules that are on the PYTHONPATH, like packages that have been installed or scripts that you have created. You use this in the files where you're writing code, or straight into your running python instance like is described here above.

For installing packages use e.g. pip, and use a virtual environment for each project you work on.

Comment: I thought I did that because I typed 'python' in before the import command?

Comment: Yes, so importing modules is for you want to use already installed packages in either code you are writing ('import script1b' at the top of your file), or in a running instance of python (e.g. when starting python in terminal to do quick calculations or testing code snippets). But I get the feeling you are trying to install packages, is that true or have you already installed scriptb1 and want to import it?

Comment: `import is for importing modules from packages that have already been installed into your python stack` import is for importing modules that are on the PYTHONPATH, such as his own script in the example above, it need not be code that was installed into his python environment

Comment: so first I should install it to put it on the 'python path'?

Comment: something like ''' pip install script1b.py''' ?

Comment: If it is a package you wrote, then try some of the instructions given here: https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/language/reusing_code.html under "How modules are found and imported".  And maybe also check out the section on "Creating modules".  Otherwise, when installing publically available packages, you would use pip.

Comment: thanks for the link, seems I have a downvote? I haven't had one of those before. Can someone kindly provide pointers as to what exactly I did wrong? Helpful kind comments much appreciated.

Comment: I think more information would be key, also for getting more useful answers.  Here you could e.g. be more clear about the end goal, and at first I misunderstood that script1b was a local .py file and not a public python package.  Maybe also say where script1b is at, what you have in your pythonpath etc.