# Unable to run my test file using pytest framework

Tags: python, pytest

I have python application and tried to write a test cases. These test cases are importing actual functions resides in my src folder. In IDE, I don't find any error. But when I execute I am getting as below.

My project structure is

```
myapplication
  |-> src
       |->my_app
           |->utils
                |-> Utils.py
  |-> config
  |-> data
  |-> tests
        |-> test_my_app
              |-> test_utils
                     |->test_Utils.py
```

My utils.py has below code snippet which has import of utils function from src which throws me an error.

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime
from src.my_app.utils.Utils import Utils

# Define test cases
def test_roundOff():
    assert Utils.roundOff(12.345) == 12.35
    assert Utils.roundOff(10.0) == 10.0
    assert Utils.roundOff(9.999) == 10.0

def test_getMarketStartTime():
    now = datetime(2023, 10, 11, 9, 0, 0)
    market_start = Utils.getMarketStartTime(now)
    assert market_start == datetime(2023, 10, 11, 9, 15, 0)

def test_getMarketEndTime():
    now = datetime(2023, 10, 11, 16, 0, 0)
    market_end = Utils.getMarketEndTime(now)
    assert market_end == datetime(2023, 10, 11, 15, 30, 0)

# You can add more test functions for other methods in the Utils class

# Run the tests with pytest
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main()
```

The error I am facing is

```
    (venv) PS C:\Users\mylaptop\PycharmProjects\myapplication> pytest
================================================================================= test session starts =================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.9, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\mylaptop\PycharmProjects\myapplication
collected 0 items / 1 error

======================================================================================= ERRORS ========================================================================================
___________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_my_app/test_utils/test_Utils.py ___________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\mylaptop\PycharmProjects\myapplication\tests\test_my_app\test_utils\test_Utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_my_app\test_utils\test_Utils.py:3: in <module>
    from src.my_app.utils.Utils import Utils
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
=============================================================================== short test summary info =============================================================================== 
ERROR tests/test_my_app/test_utils/test_Utils.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
================================================================================== 1 error in 0.60s ===================================================================================
```

What I tried is

1. Deleted pytest_cache folder and retried
2. I am able to test same test cases using run option available in pyCharm. It was working. But not able to test via terminal available in pyCharm which results above error.
3. File->settings. Default test framework was selected as "pytest"
4. tried below list of commands
5. pytest
   pytest -v tests/test_my_app/test_utils/test_Utils.py
   pytest -m test_Utils -k test_my_app/test_utils
6. Placed empty **init**.py file under src,my_app and utils folder
7. I have set my project path till /src folder in system environment variable. Restarted machine.
8. Marked src folder as "source" folder in pyCharm and removed all src. from import statement.

After trying all these options still I am getting same error.

My envinronment is Python 3.10 and pytest. Using PyCharm as IDE.
None of these options are not working. Please show me some light to resolve this issue.

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049663/python3-6-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-src, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078689/module-not-found-error-no-module-named-src?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks! I have updated src folder as source folder and removed src. Still it was throw next directory which my_app is not found. Tried setting pythonpath as well. No luck.

Comment: check `sys.path` when you are running from pycharm vs terminal